# WPF Property Target for Style Trigger

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I'm defining a custom DataGridTextColumn with the added "Tag" property on a DataGrid as follows

```
<local:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Company}" 
                          Header="Company" 
                          Tag="String" 
                          IsReadOnly="True" />
```

I've defined some resource XAML to control the rendering of the grid, but I have a problem. I would like to render a custom ContextMenu on DataGridColumnHeader depending on the value of "Tag" property using triggers. However, I cannot find a way to reference the columns "Tag" value from the style. I've tried DataTriggers and regular Triggers.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
<Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:DataGridTextColumn}, Path=Tag}" Value="String">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderContextMenuString}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Int">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderContextMenuInt}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="DateTime">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderContextMenuDateTime}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get from the styled `DataGridColumnHeader` element to the underlying column.  From there, you can drill into the `Tag`.  Try this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Column.Tag}" 
             Value="String">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu"
            Value="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderContextMenuString}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

But if you're going to use header styles, why not simply have a style for each underlying data type, and set each column's `HeaderStyle` accordingly?  You won't need the trigger if each header style only applies to a single data type.

Comment: Thanks Mike. It didn't work me I'm afraid. I'm trying to make the styling generic that I can apply to multiple DataGrids without styling each one independently.

Comment: Odd.  What was the binding error?  I assume your grid is based on the standard WPF grid, so it should have the `Column` property, yes?

Comment: Yes, it extends DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Do not enforce style decisions at design time, by changing the Tag property, to apply a style at runtime. Why?

If you can change the Tag at design time, you can have the column header adhere to a specific style.

It is unclear why the *Rube Goldberg* way of setting a design time style is needed.

Comment: Mine is a custom DataGrid class that will apply to many DataGrids. The above is part of a larger styling that is set in a theme applied to the application as a whole. Which I thought was the XAML way. Do you have a suggestion that would lead to a better solution?

Comment: @BigBadOwl I understood there was a need to change verses different situations. But styles are inherited. If page X needs style Y it should `override` the styles on the page (or even the grid level down to the actual instance of the datagrid) and when the datagrid picks up on that it will style per the *pages* need. HTH

Answer (score 0):

There is no **Tag** property in DataGridColumnHeader base type.
Use:`<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DataGridTextColumn}">` and simple Triggers

Answer (score 0):

Well! Everything is going fine in your work but there is a little bit concept required to solve the problem:

**Key Concept:** (Optional Reading Material) Header property of ‘DataGridTextColumn’ process two types of data in it, one is Type:string and other is ‘Type:DataGridColumnHeader’. In contrast to many other Framework Properties, string type value will not convert into other type at compile time. So setting value Header="Company" remain in sting data type and it is meaning less to set ContextMenu property.

There are many solutions/ways to resolve this problem but I am posting the answer that is near to your approach ….

**Solution:** Set style as you are doing but set the header property as follow:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CompanyColumn" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Company}">
     <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
         <DataGridColumnHeader Content="Company" Tag="String"/>
     </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
 </DataGridTextColumn>
```

To support other visitor I am sending the complete code to understand this approach.

```
<Window x:Class="AnswerNo1.SolutionA" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="SolutionA" Height="250" Width="400">
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ColumnHeaderContextMenuString">
        <MenuItem Header="_Sentence case."/>
        <MenuItem Header="_lowercase"/>
        <MenuItem Header="_UPPERCASE"/>
        <MenuItem Header="_Capitalize Each Word"/>
        <MenuItem Header="_tOGGLE cASE"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ColumnHeaderContextMenuInt">
        <MenuItem Header="Show _SUM"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Show _Mean"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Show Standard Deviation"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Subtract All Form ..."/>
        <MenuItem Header="Toggle Sign"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ColumnHeaderContextMenuDateTime">
        <MenuItem Header="Show Time Graph"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Show Minimum Data"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Show Maximum Data"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Show Mode Day"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Sort by day name"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="String">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderContextMenuString}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Int">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderContextMenuInt}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="DateTime">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderContextMenuDateTime}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="YourDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="3">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CompanyColumn" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Company}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridColumnHeader Content="Company" Tag="String"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ReputationColumn" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Reputation}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridColumnHeader Content="Reputation" Tag="Int"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="SetupDateColumn" Width="*" Binding="{Binding SetupDate}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridColumnHeader Content="Setup Date" Tag="DateTime"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Tag for 1st Column: "/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" SelectedItem="{Binding Header.Tag, ElementName=CompanyColumn}" >
            <System:String>String</System:String>
            <System:String>Int</System:String>
            <System:String>DateTime</System:String>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please only post anything that is relevant to the question and not extra reading materials.

Answer (score 0):

I ended-up having to write a non XAML solution for this. It was the only way to get a re-usable DataGrid with content aware context-menus. The other solutions all required copious amounts of configuration every time a grid is added (plus I couldn't get them to work).